# Adminer cant PREPARE what SQL Fiddle could

Tags: mysql

today I tried to switch rows for columns in SQL fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9c1a66/1 (dont know if you can open my version) but it worked great.

The problem is whenewer i try to execute this query in adminer or via php i get error in

```
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql
```

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.

If someone will have the same problem dont forget use ´´ quotas for every column name